# How do I setup nginx for multiple web app with multiple subdomains in GCE

Tags: nginx, server, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am using GCE with LEMP stack. I have multiple subdomains and each subdomain has different root folder.

My setup is as below:

Production app

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl http2;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;

    server_name prod.example.com;
    root /var/www/example/web;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
        #   When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        #   current version of your application, you should pass the real
        #   application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        #   FPM.
        #   Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        #   your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        #   for more information).
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        #   Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        #   http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        #   Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
            internal;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Staging app

```
server {
    #listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com.key;

    server_name staging.example.com;
    root /var/www/example-staging/web;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
        #   When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        #   current version of your application, you should pass the real
        #   application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        #   FPM.
        #   Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        #   your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        #   for more information).
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        #   Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        #   http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        #   Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
            internal;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

They have the same config except for the server_name part. But, it seems like nginx is not able to tell apart the 2 different configuration.

No matter if I were to use prod.example.com or staging.example.com, both will only route to the prod root folder.

Is there anything wrong with my configurations that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of my "staging" app is listening to IPv6 only, I need to turn on IPv4 too, so now the different subdomains are routing correctly.